# Adding chars to char array from csv.

Tags: c

I am trying to take a csv file and assign the strings from it to a csv. I've tried a couple of things with very little luck. This is what I have so far:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv []) {
    FILE *file = fopen( argv[1], "r" );
    int x;
    char strings[50];
    while  ((x = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
        printf( "%c", x);
    }
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

I've created the strings char array, but I'm unsure how to assign the contents of my csv into it. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Behavior that you desire is unclear.

Comment: Show few rows of your csv file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) to directly read into array `strings`-

```
char strings[255];                                    //give size accordingly
while(fgets(strings,sizeof strings,file)!=NULL) {     //iteratre until fgets return NULL 
    printf("%s", strings);                            //print string that is read from file
}
```

**Note**-

1.You have not checked value of `argc` as well as `return` of `fopen` . You should probably check them .

Answer (score 0):

You can use your characterwise reading approach. Fill your temporary buffer as you go, but take care not to overflow it. When you encounter a separator – a comma for columns, a newline for rows – process the current buffer.

Reset the buffer, adjust the current row and column and repeat until you find the end of the file. When you want to store the content of a cell, be sure to make a copy, because the scratch buffer will be overwritten.

Here's a simple example that just prints the data:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *file = fopen("example.csv", "r");
    // check for errors

    char buf[50];
    int nbuf = 0;

    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;

    for (;;) {
        int c = fgetc(file);

        if (c == EOF) break;

        if (c == '\n' || c == ',') {
            buf[nbuf] = '\0';
            printf("[%d][%d] '%s'\n", row, col, buf);
            nbuf = 0;

            if (c == ',') {
                col++;
            } else {
                col = 0;
                row++;
            }      
        } else {
            if (nbuf + 1 < sizeof(buf)) buf[nbuf++] = c;
        }        
    }

    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```